# How to select field but filter 1 or 2 other filed max first

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How to select field but filter  1 or 2 other filed max first

```
aid  bid  cid
0    1    0
1    2    1    <---  this row   get aid
2    0    2    <--- not this row

// this only filter 1 field
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT MAX(aid) as aid FROM tb");
$sth->execute();
$row = $aid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: use a where condition according to your requirement or use GROUP BY  and HAVING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a `where` statement:

```
SELECT MAX(aid) as aid
FROM tb
where bid > 0;
```

I would suggest that you study up a bit on the SQL language, so you are at least familiar with its most basic constituents.

EDIT:

If you want the maximum value of `aid` where `bid` is max, then try this:

```
select tb.*
from tb
order by bid desc, cid desc
limit 1;
```

That is, order the rows and take the first row.

Comment: > 0?  I wrote like this  "SELECT MAX(aid) as aid FROM tb" where MAX(bid) then MAX(cid)   I know this is wrong but I can't find the syntax  select MAX(b) then MAX(c) then MAX(a)